# Making a CLI based Java calculator

Tags: java, command-line-interface, calculator

I want to make a simple calculator but, I don't know how to enter many operations just like a real calculator.

```
switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Please enter 2 numbers only: " );
                x = input.nextInt();
                y = input.nextInt();
                sum = calc.add(x,y);
                System.out.printf("The sum is %d\n\n",sum);
                out.write(x + "+" + y + "=" + sum);
                break;       
            case 2:
              ...
            case 3:
            ...
        }
```

Comment: Sum only refers to addition. Multiplied numbers are a product; divided numbers are a quotient; subtracted numbers are a difference.

Comment: Also, you repeat the same first 3 lines in each case.  You could probably move that out to a function or just initial prompt and then have the case be based on which operation they choose. Oh, and Modulo  I think would be remainder and exponents are weird and can be called products or powers.

Comment: I took the liberty to remove the exact repetitions in the code. It added zero information and forced everyone to find out for himself that it's just copypasta.

Answer (score 2):

There is no question but I have some suggestions.

I would

- make the case statements based on the operation '+', instead of 1.
- make the messages match the operations. e.g. `write(x + "*" + y` when multiplying. Also don't call them all "sum"
- make sure I read the nextLine() at the end.
- write a new line after each line.
- add a `default:` when the user enters an unknown operation.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`ScriptEngine`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html).  E.G. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441625/how-to-find-a-button-source-in-awt-calculator-homework/7441804#7441804).

[image] = [image]

That has a GUI (obviously) but you could simply allow the user to type in whatever formula JS can handle.  Here is another [example](http://pscode.org/jse.html) at my site that allows formula entry by text field.